# Controlling the tubes for Queued Events in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, beanstalkd

So I've started using Queued Events in L5 for handling some logic and I was wondering if it was possible to tell laravel what tube to use when pushing the events onto Beanstalkd.

I couldn't see anything in the documentation about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging through the [Event Dispatcher code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php#L422-L437).

I found that if there is a queue method on your event handler laravel will pass the arguments through to that method and let you call the push  method manually.

So if you have a `SendEmail` event handler you can do something like this:

```
<?php namespace App\Handlers\Events;

use App\Events\UserWasCreated;

use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeQueued;

class SendEmail implements ShouldBeQueued {
    use InteractsWithQueue;

    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function queue($queue, $job, $args)
    {
        // Manually call push
        $queue->push($job, $args, 'TubeNameHere');
        // Or pushOn
        $queue->pushOn('TubeNameHere', $job, $args);
    }

    public function handle(UserWasCreated $event)
    {
        // Handle the event here
    }
}
```